Typescript Decorator: how to get type of a property
I try to simplify my flow of handling data from Strapi, converting it using interfaces and converting back to Strapi format using three different mapping functions. For people who don't know Strapi, I just mean I get data in a format and handle it in another one.
I wanted to create model classes with custom @field decorators containing the Strapi corresponding name. For instance:
export class MyModel {
    @field("name_in_strapi")
    name: type;

    …
}

My decorator is the following one:
function field(value: any) {
    return (_target: any, context: Context) => {
        if (context.metadata == undefined) {
            context.metadata = {};
        }
        context.metadata[context.name] = value;
    };
}

But I am stuck on complex class properties using other models, because I can't retrieve data type from a class. Indeed, I need to know the type of a property if it's another model, to create it.
Finally, I'm completely stuck, because I don't know what to do, and if I should try to use decorators to do what I want.
I don't know if I was clear, but could you help me? Thanks!

You can achieve this using the reflect-metadata module and activating emitDecoratorMetadata in tsconfig.json.
Then you will have to write something like this:
class AnotherModel {}

interface Context {
  name: string;
  private: false;
  static: false;
}

// Define the decorator
function field(strapiName: string) {
  return (
    target: undefined,
    context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<MyModel,AnotherModel|null>&Context
  ): void => {
    // Accesss the type metadata of property with name context.name
    const propType = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, context.name);
    // Save all the metadata as one object
    Reflect.defineMetadata("app-metadata", { strapiName, propType }, target, context.name);
  }
}

// Apply the decorator
export class MyModel {
    @field("name_in_strapi")
    someProp: AnotherModel | null = null;;
}

// Read the metadata
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("app-metadata", MyModel, "name"));
// { strapiName: "name_in_strapi", propType: AnotherModel }

The type information has some limitations:

TypeScript only supports basic type serialization. The basic type serialization rules are:

number serialized as Number
string serialized as String
boolean serialized as Boolean
any serialized as Object
void serializes as undefined
Array serialized as Array
If a Tuple, serialized as Array
If a class serialized it as the class constructor
If an Enum serialized it as Number
If has at least one call signature, serialized as Function
Otherwise serialized as Object (Including interfaces)


If you need more info, read this.

Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. But isn’t reflect-metadata already abandoned? Isn’t there a more "TypeScript 5.2" way?

If you are going to use the new way, you will need to pass the type also to the decorator field<T>(strapiName: string, type T) without reflect-metadata there is no automated way to get the types.

Thanks! That's what I understood, but I wasn't totally sure. Maybe someday in an update…
